# Creating object Nodes an easier way

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

I am required to create a bunch of object nodes to an object:

```
this.selectedText = e.text;
this.clipNo = e.clipNo;

if(!this.clipCollection.hasOwnProperty(this.category)) {
    this.clipCollection[this.category] = {};
}

if(!this.clipCollection.hasOwnProperty("grandClipCount")) {
    this.clipCollection.grandClipCount = 0;
}

if(!this.clipCollection[this.category].hasOwnProperty(['pageNo'+this.pageNumber])) {
    this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber] = {};
    this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].pageServerInfo = this.pageServerInfo;
}

if(!this.clipCollection[this.category][this.category+"ClipCount"]) {
    this.clipCollection[this.category][this.category+"ClipCount"] = 0;
}

if(!this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].hasOwnProperty("clips")) {
    this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].clips = {};
    this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].clips['clip'+this.clipNo] = this.selectedText;
    this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].pageClipCount = 0;
}

this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].clips['clip'+this.clipNo] = this.selectedText;
this.clipCollection[this.category]['pageNo'+this.pageNumber].pageClipCount += 1;
this.clipCollection[this.category][this.category+"ClipCount"] += 1;
this.clipCollection.grandClipCount += 1;
```

Is there a short approach to minimize this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters maybe get rid of `this` with a few local variables and
give names to often used constants, e.g.

```
var pageNo = 'pageNo'+this.pageNumber;
```

or so.

The blocks with `hasOwnProperty` checks can be replaced with a
conditional:

```
this.clipCollection[this.category] = this.clipCollection[this.category] || {};

this.clipCollection.grandClipCount = (this.clipCollection.grandClipCount || 0) + 1;
```

And so on.